# How to record live streaming in agora

Tags: android, live-streaming, agora.io, agora

I am implementing the agora live streaming app. live streaming working perfectly.

Now I want to record that live streaming is possible in the agora

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CloudRecording APIs which Agora provides. Find the reference to the API documentation here: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/develop/individual-mode

It mainly involves three steps: Acquire, Start, and Stop.

Make sure that you have the auth tokens set up and the relevant storage (S3/Azure Blob) set up for this as you need to pass on the accessKeys as part of the storage config to Agora APIs.